# JQUERY: why isn't my nav fixed to the top when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you scroll 100px down the page i wont my navigation bar to become fixed to the top. and then when scrolled back up it goes back to its normal state.

I have managed to get the nav bar to become fixed and unfixed when scrolling however its not in the right position. it fixes down the page and to the left, instead of at the top and floated to the right.

Here is my example i made on jsfiddle for you to look at.

http://jsfiddle.net/edL5F/20/

```
       <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="codeback">
            </div>
            <div id="container">

                 <div class="nav">
                 </div>
                 <div id="wrap">

                 </div>
            </div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->

       </div>


 body{
    background-color:black;
}

    #wrapper{
        width:100%; 
        height:inherit;
    }
    #codeback{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-image:url('capture.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position:fixed;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        z-index:-1;

    }
    #container{
        width:100%;
        float:right;
    }
    .nav{
        margin-top:100px;
        width:80%;
        height:50px;
        float:right;
        background-color:blue;
        position:relative;
    }


    #wrap{
        float:right;
        width:80%;
        height:1500px;
        background-color:white;
    }





 $(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $el = $('.nav');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
        $('.nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'});
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
        $('.nav').css({ 'position': 'relative'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it easly with class...

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $el = $('.nav');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.nav').addClass("fixedNav");
    }else {
        $('.nav').removeClass("fixedNav");
    }
});

.fixedNav {
    position:fixed;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yss9hz0v/

Answer (score 1):

Because the .nav element has a `margin-top: 100px;` in its css properties...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edL5F/24/

Answer (score 1):

`float:right` hasn't any affect when position is `fixed`. So when you set your element to position `fixed` you have to set `right:0px`.

In the end you have to change your `margin-top` every time you change elements position from `fixed` to `relative` in to `0px` and `100px`
 respectively

Try:

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $el = $('.nav');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
        $('.nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0','right':'0','margin-top':'0px'});
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
        $('.nav').css({ 'position': 'relative','margin-top':'100px'});
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/edL5F/23/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1. Remove `margin-top` form `.nav`
2. Add `padding-top:100px` to `#container`
3. Edit jquery.

Jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $el = $('.nav');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
        $('.nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0','right':'0'});
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
        $('.nav').css({ 'position': 'relative','margin-top':'100px'});
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edL5F/26/).

Explanation: 
`right:0` is to attach the `.nav` to the right after it goes fixed.

The margin to padding change is to force the bar to go back to it's original position, when you scroll up, without editing any css.